Handling NA Values in ppm() with spatstat: Excluding Sea Areas from Random Sampling
I’m currently using the spatstat package in R to fit a point process model (ppm()) on spatial data from an island study area. My dataset includes several spatial covariates, such as elevation, slope, and similar variables. The spatial extent I’m working with includes both land (the island itself) and surrounding sea areas. As expected, the covariates are only meaningful over land, and the sea areas are marked as NA.
The issue arises when fitting a ppm() model: as far as I understand, spatstat internally generates random points across the entire bounding box to sample covariate values, and some of these points fall in the sea, where the covariates are NA. This results in a warning indicating that a certain percentage of points have NA values.
To temporarily bypass this, I’ve been setting NA values to zero in the covariate images. However, I’m concerned this approach may skew the modeling or introduce artifacts since it effectively assigns a value to regions that should ideally be excluded.
Here’s a simplified example to illustrate the issue:
# Define a window that represents the entire bounding box (3x3 square)
W <- square(3)

# Create a covariate image (elevation) where only a circular "island" has values, and the rest is NA
elev <- as.im(function(x, y) ifelse((x^2 + y^2) < 1, sin(pi * x) * cos(pi * y), NA), W)
plot(elev, main = "Elevation with NA values outside island area")

# Generate a random point pattern within the window
set.seed(42) # For reproducibility
pp <- rpoispp(10, win = W) # Example point pattern

# Attempt to fit a ppm model using the elevation covariate
model <- spatstat.model::ppm(pp ~ elev, covariates = list(elev = elev))

When I run this, I receive the following warning:
> model <- spatstat.model::ppm(pp ~ elev, covariates = list(elev = elev))
Warning message:
Values of the covariate ‘elev’ were NA or undefined at 90% (1023 out of 1131) of the quadrature points. Occurred while executing: ppm.ppp(Q = pp, trend = ~elev, data = NULL, interaction = NULL,

To the best of my understanding, this warning reflects the fact that ppm() is sampling points in areas with NA values, analogous to the sea areas in my actual dataset.
I’m looking for guidance on best practices for handling this scenario. Should I continue with the current workaround, or is there a sounder approach to exclude sea areas from random point sampling in ppm()?

A warning is only a warning, it doesn't necessarily mean something fatally wrong has happened. Can you give us some code that shows the problem, perhaps by modifying one of the examples from ?ppm and introducing some NA values in a data set?

thank you. I have edited the questions to address your comment.

If the elevation is truly meaningless at the sea locations, then the points in the sea can provide no information about how the model depends on elevation.
I suggest you drop all your points that are in the sea, and redefine your window to be the area where elevation is not NA. You'll lose some data points but they have missing covariates and so cannot contribute to the model anyway.
Its possible spatstat is already doing this for you, since the fitted model only plots in the non-NA area.

Thank you for the suggestion. Just to clarify: the issue isn’t with my observed points, which are already confined to land areas with defined covariates. The problem arises because ppm() generates internal random points across the bounding box, some of which fall in sea areas where covariates (like elevation) are NA. This results in a warning that a certain percentage of points have NA values in the covariates. Is there a way to handle this in spatstat so that sampling during model fitting occurs only over land? Apologies should I am missing something.

Is the window of your points set to the bounding box? It should perhaps only be the land area, as a polygon or im object. Then it seems spatstat doesn't generate quadrature points outside the window, producing NA warnings.

Thank you for your patience. I think part of the confusion might be due to the shape of my study area, so let me clarify with some additional context.
The study area I’m working with is the island of Malta, which has a highly irregular coastline with many inlets and protrusions. Because of the shape, the rectangular bounding box that encompasses the island (and which includes my PP) naturally includes a significant amount of surrounding sea. This results in a bounding box that covers both the land (Malta itself) and the surrounding sea area, where the values of the covariate(s) are NA.

Yes, but if your PP is only sensible on land (eg its bird nest sites) then your window must define the area where any points that may have occurred have been detected, ie the boundary of the land and not the bounding box. A bounding box window only makes sense if you have points that could occur anywhere in that bounding box.

Thank you. I understand now that the observation window should ideally follow the boundary of the land area rather than the bounding box. Could you advise on how to define a window that follows the land boundary within spatstat? I assume I need to create a custom polygonal window to match the island's coastline, but I'm unsure of the exact steps to implement this.
Any specific guidance or examples on setting up a precise observation window for an irregular shape like Malta would be greatly appreciated.

That's very much a whole new question, you'd have to find boundary data for Malta, read into R with the sf package, convert to spatstat's polygon format etc, or I think spatstat can also use a binary 0/1 raster to define irregular windows.

Just to clarify, I do have boundary data for Malta and am already working with it in R. My main challenge is how to use this boundary to restrict the quadrature points generated by ppm() to the land area only, rather than across the entire bounding box.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I wanted to share the solution I found for setting the correct boundary for my ppp object. Since my study area is an island, I needed to restrict the point pattern to the land area only, excluding the surrounding sea.
The solution involved using my existing boundary polygon (e.g., boundary_polygon), which is a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame, and converting it directly into an owin object in spatstat. This allowed me to set it as the observation window for my ppp object, confining the analysis to the land area. Here’s the process I followed.
Convert the Boundary Polygon to an owin Object:
With spatstat.geom, I converted boundary_polygon (a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame containing the boundary of my study area) directly to an owin object. This defined the land area as the observation window in spatstat.
library(spatstat.geom)
observation_window <- as.owin(boundary_polygon)

Set the Window of the ppp Object:
Next, I applied this window to my point pattern (point_pattern), ensuring that all analyses were limited to the land area.
Window(point_pattern) <- observation_window

This was pretty straightforward and effective, allowing me to precisely limit the observation window to the land boundary of my study area.

You should do this when you create the point_pattern object initially.
